# How to create personal certificate

Tags: c#, .net, certificate

i am using this code for certificate generation o local machine.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(cerFilePath,password);
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(certificate);
        store.Close();
```

output shows it's created but it is not in the personal tab of certmanager but if i use Store Name other than My (example: Trusted Publisher ) in same program, certificate is available in cert manager under that storename.

but i need certificate for personal use.

what is going wrong?

Comment: Is this a Windows App, and with which user it runs? Under current user? So in the executing context, who is "Me", resp. which store is "StoreName.My" ?

Comment: I am running visual studio in Admin Mode and yes, it is c# project in VC in which i need to create a certificate by taking .pfx file as input.

Comment: It all sounds like an impersonation issue with the current provided info. Can you print out some debug info about the current user(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentPrincipal), just to make sure the app is really executing as your own user, and not impersonating, or to print out the current contents of Store.My at the code, to see if this is really the expected Store to put certs in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "LocalMachine" context, you must have "Elevated Privileges" (**Run the application as an administrator if needed**).

Both "LocalMachine" and "CurrentUser" have a store named "Personal" (My) !

You can browse the "LocalMachine" store with "certlm.msc", and use "certmgr.msc" to browse "CurrentUser" store.